# PBRT: requests sample dimensions in the same order

Tags: sampling, pbrt

[PBRT 7.2.2](https://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Sampling_and_Reconstruction/Sampling_Interface#BasicSamplerInterface) illustrates an example on `requests sample dimensions in the same order`:

```
sampler->StartPixel(p);
do {
  Float v = a(sampler->Get1D());
  if (v > 0)
      v += b(sampler->Get1D());
  v += c(sampler->Get1D());
} while (sampler->StartNextSample());
```

> In this case, the first dimension of the sample vector will always be passed to the function a(); when the code path that calls b() is executed, b() will receive the second dimension. However, if the if test isn’t always true or false, then c() will sometimes receive a sample from the second dimension of the sample vector and otherwise receive a sample from the third dimension. Thus, efforts by the sampler to provide well-distributed sample points in each dimension being evaluated have been thwarted.

So I'm trying to understand this concept by fixing the code: to keep samples always in the same order, we can always prepare a sample for `b()`, use it when the if test returns true and discard it otherwise:

```
sampler->StartPixel(p);
do {
  Float v = a(sampler->Get1D());
  auto second_sample = sampler->Get1D();
  if (v > 0)
      v += b(second_sample);
  v += c(sampler->Get1D());
} while (sampler->StartNextSample());
```

After fixing, the 1st sample always go to `a()`, 2nd goes to `b()` and 3rd goes to `c()` thus the order is maintained.

Do I understand it correctly? Is my fix correct?